# Enabling EAP and async/await on same class

Tags: c#, events, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm trying create a class that has events AND can be awaitable, but keep coming across stumbling blocks.

First, I tried a `TransferJob` class that returns a `TransferTask` object which is already running when it is returned.  This would be accomplished through something like this:

```
public abstract class TransferJob
{
    public TransferTask Start()
    {
        return Start(CancellationToken.None);
    }

    public TransferTask Start(CancellationToken token)
    {
        TransferTask task = CreateTransferTask();
        task.Start(token);

        return task;
    }

    protected abstract TransferTask CreateTransferTask();
}

public abstract class TransferTask
{
    public event EventHandler<TransferStatusChangedEventArgs> StatusChanged;

    private Task transferTask;
    private TransferStatus status;

    public TransferStatus Status
        {
            get { return this.status; }
            protected set
            {
                TransferStatus oldStatus = this.status;
                this.status = value;

                OnStatusChanged(new TransferStatusChangedEventArgs(oldStatus, value));
            }
        }

    internal void Start(CancellationToken token)
    {
        this.transferTask = TransferAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    protected abstract Task TransferAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);

    protected virtual void OnStatusChanged(TransferStatusChangedEventArgs txStatusArgs)
        {
            if (this.StatusChanged != null)
            {
                this.StatusChanged(this, txStatusArgs);
            }
        }

    public TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter()
    {
        return this.transferTask.GetAwaiter();
    }
}
```

The problem with the above is that if the TransferTask finishes very quickly, then users of TransferJob.Start() might not have time to register their event handlers on the returned TransferTask's StatusChanged event before it finishes.  So I tried a different approach whereby the user has to call the TransferTask's Start() method themselves.  This would give the user time to register their event handlers on the `TransferTask` in between the `transferJob.CreateTask()` call and the `transferTask.Start()` call:

```
public abstract class TransferJob
{
    public abstract TransferTask CreateTask();
}

public abstract class TransferTask
{
    public event EventHandler<TransferStatusChangedEventArgs> StatusChanged;

    private Task transferTask;
    private TransferStatus status;

    public TransferStatus Status
        {
            get { return this.status; }
            protected set
            {
                TransferStatus oldStatus = this.status;
                this.status = value;

                OnStatusChanged(new TransferStatusChangedEventArgs(oldStatus, value));
            }
        }

    public void Start(CancellationToken token)
    {
        this.transferTask = TransferAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    protected abstract Task TransferAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);

    protected virtual void OnStatusChanged(TransferStatusChangedEventArgs txStatusArgs)
        {
            if (this.StatusChanged != null)
            {
                this.StatusChanged(this, txStatusArgs);
            }
        }

    public TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter()
    {
        return this.transferTask.GetAwaiter();
    }
}
```

Now, I have a different problem.  If a user tries `await transferTask;` before `transferTask.Start();` has been called, then presumably they'll get a `NullReferenceException` thrown because the task hasn't been started (and therefore assigned to the `transferTask` field).  I'm really struggling for a way to solve this.  Is there a way?  Or a better pattern to use than the above?

Comment: On the more designy aspect of your question, what benefit is there to mixing those patterns, which do the same in different ways? What will you gain from both that you wont gain from choosing either?

Comment: What benefit is there to implementing two related patterns, which have plenty of libraries for converting between? If you need to use EAP on a TAP class, well actually the Task does support EAP. If you need TAP on EAP, you can use Rx.Net.

Comment: Something similar to a factory pattern where TransferJob might be an FtpTransferJob that holds settings to a particular FTP host, and CreateTask returns an FtpTransferTask that transfers a file to the host. In my mind, it is similar to a TaskFactory returning a Task, in that you create a Task through the TaskFactory and it is returned already running.  Or do you mean why both EAP and Task?

Comment: @dark_perfect They both do the same thing, and in fact if you look at the signature of `Task<T>` you'll find that it has a completion event.

Comment: Using the StatusChanged event, I can provide intermediary events such as Localised, Connecting, Transferring etc, but with the task I can only really make user aware of whether the task is running or is complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really convinced this is a good idea. Just expose the TAP pattern. Delete the event as well as `transferTask`. The caller of `Start` must hold onto that task and pass it to any code that wants to listen for completion. This results in a very clean API. No mutable state, very simple to understand, supports all use cases.

If you insist, you can create a proxy task that looks like it's the real thing:

```
public abstract class TransferTask
{
    public event EventHandler<TransferStatusChangedEventArgs> StatusChanged;

    private TaskCompletionSource<object> transferTask = new ...; //changed
    private TransferStatus status;

    public TransferStatus Status
        {
            get { return this.status; }
            protected set
            {
                TransferStatus oldStatus = this.status;
                this.status = value;

                OnStatusChanged(new TransferStatusChangedEventArgs(oldStatus, value));
            }
        }

    public Task Start(CancellationToken token)
    {
        await TransferAsync(cancellationToken);
        transferTask.SetResult(null); //complete proxy task
    }

    protected abstract Task TransferAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);

    protected virtual void OnStatusChanged(TransferStatusChangedEventArgs txStatusArgs)
        {
            if (this.StatusChanged != null)
            {
                this.StatusChanged(this, txStatusArgs);
            }
        }

    public TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter()
    {
        return this.transferTask.Task.GetAwaiter(); //changed
    }
}
```

Now, `transferTask.Task` is always not null. That task will eventually complete. I quickly hacked this together, I hope the idea is clear.

Probably, you should base the event on `transferTask.Task.ContinueWith(...)`.

Comment: Ok, this looks good.  My main issue is that I'm looking to expose the various change of statuses (Connecting, Committing etc) during the course of he transfer, and that is what the event is for.  I can't really do this with TAP, because the only status it really exposes is Start -> End (/Faulted/Cancelled).  I can expose the status through a property, but users will have to poll the property to detect changes.  I think if anything, I would prefer to remove the TAP pattern and keep the events...I just really like the idea of making it awaitable!

Comment: OK, that's a good case for events. Don't make your type awaitable though. Make it return a task. Task composes well with other tasks. Awaiters are for very special cases. Now I see no reason to keep `transferTask`. Delete all that machinery. The caller of `Start` must manage the resulting task. If you want to keep it expose a property `Task Completed` which is a standard pattern.

Comment: Fair point.  I think I probably at one point returned a Task, but it felt weird returning a Task from something that I was trying to make behave like a task.  I see the logic, however.

Comment: @dark_perfect: Consider using `IProgress<T>` instead of events if it's just status updates.

Comment: @StephenCleary Interesting! Wasn't aware of it. Just found your blog post on it too - very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found when trying to mix events and awaitable code in C# is to use the Reactive Extension (Rx) library. [From Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609):

> Reactive Extension (Rx) is a library to compose asynchronous and event-based programs using observable collections and LINQ-style query operators.

You could do something like the following to fix your issue. (I am not sure this is exactly what you want to accomplish, but the goal is just to demonstrate how Rx can be used to combine events with asynchronous code):

```
public async Task TransferAndWaitStartedAsync()
{
    var transferTask = new TransferTask();

    // Prepare the observable before executing the transfer to make sure that the observable sequence will receive the event
    // You can use Linq operators to filter only specific events. In this case, I only care about events with Status == StatusCode.Started 
    var whenStatusChanged = Observable.FromEventPattern<TransferStatusChangedEventArgs>(h, transferTask.StatusChanged += h, h => transferTask.StatusChanged -= h)
                                      .Where(e => e.EventArgs.Status == StatusCode.Started)
                                      .FirstAsync();

     // Start the transfer asynchronously
     await transferTask.TransferAsync(); 

     // Continuation will complete when receiving the first event that matches the predicate in the observable sequence even if the event was triggered too quickly.
     await whenStatusChanged; 
}
```

I find that the Rx library has a steep learning curve with all its subtleties, but when you know how to use it, it is a really powerful tool.

[Intro to Rx with lot of examples](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/00_Foreword.html)

[Design guidelines](http://file:///C:/Users/jproulx/Downloads/Rx%20Design%20Guidelines%20(3).pdf)